# Losing session variables when switching pages classic ASP

Tags: session, asp-classic, iis-7.5, session-variables

After importing a website from our test bed server, the website www.xyz.com is losing session variables when logging in. The pages it is switching between upon login are in different directories within the same domain. Once logged in, variables are passed without a problem.

The test bed version (Server 1), which is on IIS 6 is working correctly, whereas the production version (Server 2), which is on IIS 7.5 is not.

I have already deleted the Application Pool that was automatically created by IIS and switched it to the DefaultAppPool as it is setup on the test bed version.

Edit1: As per other posts on this and other sites regarding similar issues, I have removed the https bindings. Still not passing session variables

This is NOT an issue with session time-out.

Edit2: Like I said, it works as it should in IIS6, but it is also setup differently than IIS7. I hope you can follow the hierarchy below.

Format in IIS6:
www.mydomain.com
--Intranet (virtual directory)
----Subdirectory
-------rootDirectory_1 
---------login.asp
-------rootDirectory_2
---------default.asp

Format in IIS7:
www.mydomain.com
--rootDirectory_1
----login.asp
--rootDirectory_2 (virtual directory)
----default.asp

Comment: Are you moving between HTTP and HTTPS? If so set value of New ID On Secure connection IIS property in IIS GUI or web.config/applicationHost.config. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23266202/858905

Comment: When you say directories are you referring to different webapps "directories" in IIS itself?

Comment: John: This page does not move across protocols. It remains in HTTP constantly.

Comment: Silver: By directories, I mean "sister" directories (sorry, can't think of proper terminology) or virtual directories within in the same ROOT folder. For instance, the login page is in /site/adminLogin, but the landing page after the the login is /site/adminTools

Comment: Are they really "virtual directories" (configured in IIS) or just different folders on the same website?

Comment: John, these are virtual directories (configured in IIS) created from the directories in the site's home directory located on local drive on IIS server. I edited the original post to give you a better view of the issue. I hope you can follow it.